# Swift - Stored values order is completely changed in Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary, ordereddictionary

I tried to display datas which is in Dictionary format. Below, three attempts are there. First attempt, output order is completely changed. Second attempt, output order is same as input. But, in third attempt, I declared variable as NSDictionary. Exact output I received. Why this changes in Dictionary? Kindly guide me. I searched for Swift's Dictionary tag. But I couldn't found out.

```
//First Attempt
var dict : Dictionary = ["name1" : "Loy", "name2" : "Roy"]
        println(dict)

//output:
[name2: Roy, name1: Loy]

//Second Attempt
var dict : Dictionary = ["name2" : "Loy", "name1" : "Roy"]
        println(dict)

//output:
[name2: Loy, name1: Roy]
-----------------------------------------------------------

//Third Attempt With NSDictionary
var dict : NSDictionary = ["name1" : "Loy", "name2" : "Roy"]
            println(dict)

//output:
{
    name1 = Loy;
    name2 = Roy;
}
```

ANOTHER QUERY: I have used play ground to verify. My screen shot is below:

[image: play_ground_screen_shot]

Here, In NSDictionary, I gave name5 as first, but in right side name2 is displaying, then, in println, it is displaying in ascending order. Why this is happening??

[image: play_ground_screen_shot_2]

Here, In Dictionary, I gave name5 as first, but in right side name2 is displaying, then, in println, it is displaying, how it is taken on the Dictionary line. Why this is happening??

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary. You need an array of tuples

Comment: I am not sorting. I am asking, why this output get changed?

Comment: it will never be arranged the same way you input your data

Comment: but, in NSDictionary....??? Why its get arranged same as input?

Comment: I edited my question again.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is because of the definition of Dictionaries:

### Dictionary

> A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and values of the same type in an collection with no defined ordering.

There is **no** order, they might come out differently than they were put in. 
This is comparable to NSSet.

---

Edit:

### NSDictionary

> Dictionaries Collect Key-Value Pairs. Rather than simply maintaining an ordered or unordered collection of objects, an NSDictionary stores objects against given keys, which can then be used for retrieval.

There is *also* **no** order, however there is sorting on print for debugging purposes.

Comment: how to post image in comment?? I am having screen shot, it will explain my doubt clearly?

Comment: @McDonal_11 `let nsdict = NSDictionary(objects: ["bob", "ron", "roy", "jon"], forKeys: ["name4", "name6", "name1", "name2"])`

Comment: Swift::Dictionary and NSDictionary are both unordered.

Comment: NSDictionary doesn't even "mostly" maintain any order. The implementation is wholly unordered.

Answer (score 15):

You can't sort a dictionary but you can sort its keys and loop through them as follow:

```
let myDictionary = ["name1" : "Loy", "name2" : "Roy", "name3" : "Tim", "name4" : "Steve"]   // ["name1": "Loy", "name2": "Roy", "name3": "Tim", "name4": "Steve"]


let sorted = myDictionary.sorted {$0.key < $1.key}  // or {$0.value < $1.value} to sort using the dictionary values
print(sorted) // "[(key: "name1", value: "Loy"), (key: "name2", value: "Roy"), (key: "name3", value: "Tim"), (key: "name4", value: "Steve")]\n"
for element in sorted {
    print("Key = \(element.key) Value = \(element.value)" )
}
```

Comment: Finally, Dictionary will not stored in defined ordering. NSDictionary will stored in defined ordering. Is it right???

Comment: I am sorting the keys. The dictionary will never be arranged

Comment: @McDonal_11 Dictionary is an unordered set of key value pairs. NSDictionary is an ordered array of key value pairs.

Comment: NSDictionary is *not* an ordered array. It is unordered.

Answer (score 9):

A little late for the party but if you want to maintain the order then use [KeyValuePairs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyvaluepairs), the trade-off here is that if you use `KeyValuePairs` you lose the capability of maintaining unique elements in your list

```
var user: KeyValuePairs<String, String> {
    return ["FirstName": "NSDumb",
            "Address": "some address value here",
            "Age":"30"]
}
```

prints

```
["FirstName": "NSDumb", "Address": "some address value", "Age": "30"]
```

Comment: Hello @NSDumb Can dynamic data be added in this, Like we do in Dictionary For E.g : arr["name"] = someData_From_WS.

Comment: A little late still helps loads! I had this issue and I was wracking my brain out why the order was changing on my code thanks for sharing the page, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries, by nature, are not designed to be ordered, meaning that they're not supposed to be (although they can be!).

From the [Dictionaries (Swift Standard Library documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary):

> A dictionary is a type of hash table, providing fast access to the entries it contains. Each entry in the table is identified using its key, which is a hashable type such as a string or number. You use that key to retrieve the corresponding value, which can be any object. In other languages, similar data types are known as hashes or associated arrays.

This requires some basic knowledge of Data Structures, which I'll outline & oversimplify briefly.

---

### Storing associated data without a dictionary

Consider for a minute if there was no Dictionary and you had to use an array of tuples instead, to store some information about different fruits and their colors, as another answer suggested:

```swift
let array = [
   ("Apple", "Red"),
   ("Banana", "Yellow"),
   // ...
]
```

If you wanted to find the color of a fruit you'd have to loop through each element and check its value for the fruit, then return the color portion.

Dictionaries optimize their storage using [hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to store their data using a unique *hash* that represents the key that is being stored. For swift this means turning our key—in this case a `String`—into an `Int`. Swift uses `Int`-based hashes, which we know because we all read the [`Hashable` protocol documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable) and we see that `Hashable` defines a `hashValue` property that returns an `Int`.

---

### Storing associated data with a dictionary

The benefits of using a dictionary are that you get fast read access and fast write access to data; it makes "looking up" associated data easy and quick. Typically O(1) time complexity, although the apple docs don't specify, maybe because it depends on the key type's hash function implementation.

```swift
let dictionary = [
  "Apple": "Red",
  "Banana": "Yellow"
  // ...
]
```

The trade off is that the order is typically not guaranteed to be preserved. *Not guaranteed* means that you might get lucky and it might be the same order, but it's not intended to be, so don't rely on it.

As an arbitrary example, maybe the string `"Banana"` gets hashed into the number `0`, and `"Apple"` becomes `4`. Since we now have an `Int` we could, under the hood, represent our dictionary as an array of size 5:

```swift
// what things *might* look like under, the hood, not our actual code
// comments represent the array index numbers
let privateArrayImplementationOfDictionary = [
  "Yellow",  // 0
  nil,       // 1
  nil,       // 2
  nil,       // 3
  "Red",     // 4
]            // count = 5
```

You'll notice, we've converted our keys into array indices, and there are a bunch of blank spaces where we have nothing. Since we are using an array, we can insert data lightning fast, and retrieve it just as quickly.

Those `nil` spaces are reserved for more values that may come later, but this is also why when we try to get values out of a dictionary, they might be nil. So when we decide to add more values, something like:

```swift
dictionary["Lime"] = "Green"        // pretend hashValue: 2
dictionary["Dragonfruit"] = "Pink"  // pretend hashValue: 1
```

Our dictionary, under the hood, may look like this:

```swift
// what things *might* look like under, the hood, not our actual code
// comments represent the array index numbers
let privateArrayImplementationOfDictionary = [
  "Yellow",  // 0 ("Banana")
  "Pink",    // 1 ("Dragonfruit")
  "Green",   // 2 ("Lime")
  nil,       // 3 (unused space)
  "Red",     // 4 ("Apple")
]            // count = 5
```

As you can see, the values are not stored at all in the order we entered them. In fact, the keys aren't even really there. This is because the hash function has change our keys into something else, a set of `Int` values that give us valid array indices for our actual storage mechanism, an array, which is hidden from the world.

---

I'm sure that was more information than you wanted and probably riddled with many inaccuracies, but it gives you the gist of how a dictionary works in practice and hopefully sounds better than, "that's just how it works."

When searching for the actual performance of Swift dictionaries, [Is Swift dictionary ... indexed for performance? ... StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41049928/is-swift-dictionary-of-indexed-for-performance-even-for-exotic-types-uuid) had some extra possible relevant details to offer.

If you're still interested to know more details about this, you can try implementing your own dictionary as an academic exercise. I'd also suggest picking up a book on Data Structures and Algorithms, there are many to choose from, unfortunately I don't have any suggestions for you.

The deeper you get into this topic the more you'll understand why you'll want to use one particular data structure over another.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

## ✅ It is possible!

Although the `Dictionary` is not ordered, you can make it preserve the initial order by using the official **`OrderedDictionary`** from the original **[Swift Repo](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections)**

The ordered collections currently contain:

- **[Ordered Dictionary](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/tree/main/Sources/OrderedCollections/OrderedDictionary)** (That you are looking  for)
- **[Ordered Set](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/tree/main/Sources/OrderedCollections/OrderedSet)**

<sub>They said it is going to be merged in the Swift's source code soon (reference **[WWDC21](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10256)**)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Neither `NSDictionary` nor `Swift::Dictionary` orders its storage. The difference is that some `NSDictionary` objects sort their output when printing and `Swift::Dictionary` does not.

From the documentation of `-[NSDictionary description]`:

> If each key in the dictionary is an NSString object, the entries are
>   listed in ascending order by key, otherwise the order in which the
>   entries are listed is undefined. This property is intended to produce
>   readable output for debugging purposes, not for serializing data.

Comment: I stand corrected. Oddly enough, I've never relied on the order but never once has it gone out of order. Strange on my side... I always knew it to not be ordered but iOS interestingly has not shuffled the array as swift as. I shall upvote for visibility.

Comment: @op the best way to go is probably to use an array to keep track.

Comment: If you iterate through the dictionary's contents you will almost certainly see a different order. println() calls -[NSDictionary description] method which performs a sort, but other dictionary operations don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

From [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html):

> A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and values of the same type in an collection with **no defined ordering**.

Basically, order of items as seen in output is arbitrary, dependant on internal implementation of data structure, and should not be relied on.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed an issue with dictionaries. However, there's a library available to make sure the order stays the way you initialised it.

> OrderedDictionary is a lightweight implementation of an ordered dictionary data structure in Swift.
>
> The OrderedDictionary structure is an immutable generic collection which combines the features of Dictionary and Array from the Swift standard library. Like Dictionary it stores key-value pairs and maps each key to a value. Like Array it stores those pairs sorted and accessible by a zero-based integer index.

Check it out here:
https://github.com/lukaskubanek/OrderedDictionary