# For loop for Dictionary don't follow it's order in Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, dictionary

here's my code:

```
var keys: [String:String] = ["id": "ID", "domain": "Domain", "bundled_domain": "Bundled Domain", "dns": "DNS", "registrar": "Registrar", "registrar_url": "Registrar URL", "sponsoring_registrar": "Sponsoring Registrar", "created": "Created", "updated": "Updated", "expires": "Expires", "whois_server": "Whois Server", "status": "Status"]

for (key, name) in keys{
    println(key)
}
```

But the result didn't follow order of the dictionary:

[image: the result didn't follow order of the dictionary]

So how can I make my for loop follow my dictionary order? Thanks!

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered, but this might help you http://timekl.com/blog/2014/06/02/learning-swift-ordered-dictionaries/

Comment: for (keys, values) in yourDictionary.sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 }) {...}

Comment: Try using KeyValuePairs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601394/swift-stored-values-order-is-completely-changed-in-dictionary

Answer (score 3):

From [Apples Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html):

> Swift’s Dictionary type does not have a defined ordering. To iterate
>   over the keys or values of a dictionary in a specific order, use the
>   global sorted function on its keys or values property.