# How to access dictionary key via index?

Tags: dictionary, swift2

Is there a way to access dictionary keys in Swift 2 using an index?

```
var dict = ["item1":1, "item2":2, "item3":3]
dict.keys[0]
```

results in the error:

> 15:29: note: overloads for 'subscript' exist with these partially
>   matching parameter lists: (Base.Index), (Range),
>   (Self.Index)
>   print("key=" + dict.keys[i])

I saw an examples from August ([Swift: dictionary access via index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775724/swift-dictionary-access-via-index)) doing this:

```
dict.keys.array[0]
```

At least in Swift 2, there isn't an array object on dictionary keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 2 the equivalent of `dict.keys.array` would be `Array(dict.keys)`:

```
let dict = ["item1":1, "item2":2, "item3":3]

let firstKey = Array(dict.keys)[0]  // "item3"
```

*Note: of course, as dictionaries are unordered collections, "first key" of the resulting array may not have a predictable value.*

Answer (score 0):

do not rely on order of items in a dictonary, using array directly would be better in your case, you can also handle key/value in array with making array units objects.