# Is Swift dictionary of indexed for performance? Even for exotic types (UUID)?

Tags: swift, performance, dictionary, logarithm, indexed

I want to construct some arrays that will remain in order to get fast searches.
If I use something like this:

```
let dictionary: [Int:Int] = [:]
for i in 0 ..< 10000000 {
    dictionary[i] = 0
}
```

Would the query:

```
dictionary[n] == nil
```

be performed in logarithmic time?

If yes, is it the same for other types: Float, Double, String.

And finally, I need it to work with the UUID type, will it work?

Comment: `dictionary[i]` is a hash lookup on the key. It doesn't matter what type it is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Swift's `Dictionary` is implemented with a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), therefore lookups will typically be done in O(1) time, assuming a good hashing algorithm. As [@rmaddy says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41049928/is-swift-dictionary-of-indexed-for-performance-even-for-exotic-types-uuid#comment69308873_41049928), this therefore means that the *type* of key is mainly irrelevant – the only thing that really matters is whether it has a good implementation of [`hashValue`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/hashable/1540917-hashvalue), which you shouldn't have to worry about at all for standard library types.

The worst case time complexity for a hash table lookup (assuming *maximal* hash collisions) depends on how the hash table resolves the collisions. In the case of `Dictionary`, two storage schemes can be used, native or Cocoa.

From [HashedCollections.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L23):

> In normal usage, you can expect the backing storage of a Dictionary to be a 
>   NativeStorage.
>
> [...]
>
> Native storage is a hash table with open addressing and linear probing. The
>   bucket array forms a logical ring (e.g., a chain can wrap around the end of
>   buckets array to the beginning of it).

Therefore the worst case lookup time complexity is O(n), as if each element has the same hash, potentially every element will have to be searched through in order to determine if a given element exists in the table.

For Cocoa storage, a `_CocoaDictionaryBuffer` wrapper is used in order to wrap an `NSDictionary`. Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation on how it's implemented, although it's Core Foundation counterpart [`CFDictionary`'s header file](https://opensource.apple.com/source/headerdoc/headerdoc-8.5.10/ExampleHeaders/CFDictionary.h) states that:

> The access time for a value in the dictionary is guaranteed to be at
>   worst O(lg N) for any implementation, current and future

(Which sounds like it uses a balanced binary tree in order to handle collisions.)

Answer (score 1):

Dictinaries and arrays are different. You talk about arrays, but your code is using dictionaries. You could set up an array of optional Int values and use code like what you propose.

With your existing code, you're looking up a key/value pair from a dictionary. Dictinaries use hashes to do lookups, and I believe dictionary lookups are done in constant time, although I was unable to confirm that after a quick search.

### EDIT:

Check this link:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123100/collection-data-structures-swift-2

That says that both arrays and dictinaries can be as bad as `O(n•log(n))` performance, but typically give O(1).

Comment: I think Arrays use n log n to find a number, I need the equivalent of std::list in C++