# Dictionary with Integer key vs Array search complexity

Tags: ios, swift

I have struct model objects which all have unique id as property.
I need to filter my table view data source with my filter array which containts that struct model objects.
Which approach is more reasonable for to store filtered objects?

- using array with filtered objects

  ```
   func isItemFiltered(item: Item) -> Bool { 
       return fiteredItemsArray.contains(item)
   }
  ```
- using dictionary with my unique id's as a key

  ```
   func isItemFiltered(uniqueId: Int) -> Bool { 
       return filteredItemsDict[uniqueId] != nil
   }
  ```

I know that Array's search complexity is O(n). But what about Dictionary's search complexity ? It's looking O(1) to me but i'm not sure. Is it really O(1) ?

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41049928/is-swift-dictionary-of-indexed-for-performance-even-for-exotic-types-uuid

Comment: Yes it is O(1). If id is unique and you need to perform search, you should go with dictionary.