# What is meaning of "Dictionary uses two storage schemes: native storage and Cocoa storage"?

Tags: swift

When I searched swift/Dictionary.swift in order to see how swift's dictionary was implemented, I found  that "Dictionary` uses two storage schemes: native storage and Cocoa storage"

native storage is using open addressing.
cocoa storage is using like balanced binary search tree. ( [Is Swift dictionary of indexed for performance? Even for exotic types (UUID)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41049928/is-swift-dictionary-of-indexed-for-performance-even-for-exotic-types-uuid?noredirect=1&lq=1) )

How can I understand this sentence?
Should I understand this like "swift's compiler automatically compile swift's dictionary into native storage or cocoa storage" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, Swift's collection types are built from the ground up to take advantage of the strengths of Swift's features, optimized for its quirks, and so on.

But Swift's types don't exist in a vacuum. They need to routinely interoperate with existing Foundation types. If Swift has super performant awesome data structures, but each bridging to ObjC land and back caused a full copy to massage the data into whatever shape ObjC needed, then the overall performance would be totally unworkable.

So most of Swift's data structures, including strings, dictionaries, and arrays, are implemented as wrappers over one of several different storage strategies. One of them is optimal for Swift-only use, (which is used by default, or exclusively on a platform that doesn't have Objective C support, like Linux). The other is a wrapper around the Foundation counterpart, which is meant to bridge cheaply.

The easiest to explain is `Swift.String`. `Foundation.NSString` was introduced around the 80s-90s. UTF-16 was all the rage, and like the other languages of the era (Java, C#), Objective C used UTF-16 for String storage. Things progressed, and eventually we learned that UTF-8 was a much more memory dense (better for cache) and thus performant encoding, for most strings that people use. The ship had sailed for the other languages: UTF-16 was far too ingrained to migrate to UTF-8. Swift being a new language, had a chance to embrace it, which is did in Swift 5.

But now we have two worlds. `Swift.String` is using UTF-8 where possible, but all the existing Foundation/AppKit/UIKit/etc. APIs use `Foundation.NSString`, which expects UTF-16. The conversion between the two is a linear time traversal/copy of the whole string. This would be prohibitively expensive if it were done on any passing of a `Swift.String` where `Foundation.NSString` was expected (overwhelming any benefit UTF-8 might have had).

To get around this, `Swift.String` have one storage strategy that uses UTF-16, which allows it to really cheaply bridge to Objective C APIs. It also has a storage strategy for "small" strings (less than 15 UTF-8 code units), which can be packed into the String's buffer pointer directly, as a tagged pointer, without actually allocating any heap buffer at all.

You might be interested in https://swift.org/blog/utf8-string/

Comment: This is an excellent, comprehensive answer, and I learned some stuff I didn't know. (Voted)

Comment: You are so kindness. I really appreciate you with another information about utf8-stirng.  Thank you so much!