# Order changed for the parsed response when casting the response into a dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift4

I am getting a response from the remote server from which i had created a jsonObject. now when I'm iterating the response for the key "instances" which contains a value of dictionary the response is shuffled. the key element of the dictionary which is a date is not coming in sequence while printing.

here is the json response:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "apkqY19RthbN",
            "theater_id": "clzEVgztkcWB",
            "theater_audi_id": "7LFeNCaCrm8h",
            "movie_lang_id": "0VTEIjLeDxK1",
            "booking_start_date": null,
            "instances": {
                "2018-04-20": [
                    {
                        "id": "WRK81ahlWcZZ",
                        "show_time": "17:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "cDqZjYKHP2xt",
                        "show_time": "20:00:00"
                    }
                ],
                "2018-04-21": [
                    {
                        "id": "DcVQhohv9C3W",
                        "show_time": "17:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "bZOUk3AT6TMM",
                        "show_time": "20:00:00"
                    }
                ],
                "2018-04-22": [
                    {
                        "id": "5YJAydTua6b2",
                        "show_time": "17:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "qKGXgWvV0r38",
                        "show_time": "20:00:00"
                    }
                ],
                "2018-04-23": [
                    {
                        "id": "AGciEXINppMe",
                        "show_time": "17:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "YbKFBJV67hFW",
                        "show_time": "20:00:00"
                    }
                ],
                "2018-04-24": [
                    {
                        "id": "5vj9t1i5B4J3",
                        "show_time": "17:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "um7UeNPJuAcv",
                        "show_time": "20:00:00"
                    }
                ],
                "2018-04-25": [
                    {
                        "id": "AbS69J4SM4gG",
                        "show_time": "17:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "gKax9RXMLozN",
                        "show_time": "20:00:00"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

here is my code that i had tried:

```
 _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (Data, response, error) in
            if Data != nil{
                do{

                    let access = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data!, options: []) as! [String: Any]
                   // print(access)
                    if let data = access["data"] as? [[String:Any]]{
                        if let id = data[0]["id"] as? String{
                            global.showID = id
                          //  print(data)
                        }
                        var j = 0
                        for l in 0..<data.count{
                        if let instances = data[l]["instances"] as? [String:Any] {
                            print(instances)
                            for (key,obj) in instances{
                                //for (key,obj) in (instances as [String:Any]){
                                //print(key)
                                var showDetails: [ShowData] = [ShowData]()
                                if let timeObj = obj as? [[String: Any]]{
                                    var k = 0
                                    for i in 0..<timeObj.count{
                                        let showTime = timeObj[i]["show_time"]
                                        //print(showTime!)

                                        let showID = timeObj[i]["id"]
                                        //print(showID!)

                                        let a = ShowData.init(showId: showID as! String, showtime: showTime as! String)
                                        showDetails.insert(a, at: k)
                                        //print(showDetails)
                                        k += 1
                                    }
                                }
                                let a = Shows(date: key , instance: showDetails)
                                self.showsDate?.insert(a, at: j)
                                //print(self.showsDate!)
                                j += 1
                            }
                            Completion(self.showsDate!)
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }catch let e{
                    print(e)
                }
            }
            }.resume()
```

> print(instances)  when i am printing this the output is :

```
["2018-04-25": <__NSArrayI 0x143bd1ac0>(
{
    id = AbS69J4SM4gG;
    "show_time" = "17:00:00";
},
{
    id = gKax9RXMLozN;
    "show_time" = "20:00:00";
}
)
, "2018-04-24": <__NSArrayI 0x143b3aca0>(
{
    id = 5vj9t1i5B4J3;
    "show_time" = "17:00:00";
},
{
    id = um7UeNPJuAcv;
    "show_time" = "20:00:00";
}
)
, "2018-04-23": <__NSArrayI 0x143be0ce0>(
{
    id = AGciEXINppMe;
    "show_time" = "17:00:00";
},
{
    id = YbKFBJV67hFW;
    "show_time" = "20:00:00";
}
)
, "2018-04-21": <__NSArrayI 0x143b349c0>(
{
    id = DcVQhohv9C3W;
    "show_time" = "17:00:00";
},
{
    id = bZOUk3AT6TMM;
    "show_time" = "20:00:00";
}
)
, "2018-04-22": <__NSArrayI 0x143b24290>(
{
    id = 5YJAydTua6b2;
    "show_time" = "17:00:00";
},
{
    id = qKGXgWvV0r38;
    "show_time" = "20:00:00";
}
)
, "2018-04-20": <__NSArrayI 0x143bd5430>(
{
    id = WRK81ahlWcZZ;
    "show_time" = "17:00:00";
},
{
    id = cDqZjYKHP2xt;
    "show_time" = "20:00:00";
}
)
]
```

the dates are not in sequence like in the response.

Comment: Dictionary's don't guarantee key order. You might consider creating your own [`OrderedDictionary`](http://www.timekl.com/blog/2014/06/02/learning-swift-ordered-dictionaries/)

Comment: what should be the approach then to iterate the response in order.

Comment: Well, it depends. As I updated, you could look into finding an implementation of an `OrderedDictionary` or you could keep the keys in a `Array`, which would act as the "ordering" mechanism, then you could just extract the value from the `Dictionary` through the `Array`

Comment: And this is dangerously close to a duplicate of [Swift - Stored values order is completely changed in Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601394/swift-stored-values-order-is-completely-changed-in-dictionary?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Besides, from the looks of it, they dates are in date order anyway, so, you could make a copy of the `keys` (into an `Array`), so the `Array` in the direction you want and use that as a vector back into the dictionary - `timeObj[sortedKeys[0]]` or something simular

Comment: ok i am looking for the implementation of an ordered dictionary.

Comment: You could also have a look at [`Dictionary#sorted(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2298238-sorted) - which is basically the same idea - I would, however, suggest that the JSON data is badly formatted, but that's just my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary`'s don't maintain key order.

Let's just start with some basic data...

```
struct ShowData: CustomStringConvertible {
    var id: String
    var time: String
    
    var description: String {
        return "id = \(id); time = \(time)"
    }
}

var rawData: [String: [ShowData]] = [:]

rawData["2018-04-20"] = [
    ShowData(id: "WRK81ahlWcZZ", time: "17:00:00"),
    ShowData(id: "cDqZjYKHP2xt", time: "20:00:00")]
rawData["2018-04-21"] = [
    ShowData(id: "DcVQhohv9C3W", time: "17:00:00"),
    ShowData(id: "bZOUk3AT6TMM", time: "20:00:00")]
rawData["2018-04-22"] = [
    ShowData(id: "5YJAydTua6b2", time: "17:00:00"),
    ShowData(id: "qKGXgWvV0r38", time: "20:00:00")]
rawData["2018-04-23"] = [
    ShowData(id: "AGciEXINppMe", time: "17:00:00"),
    ShowData(id: "YbKFBJV67hFW", time: "20:00:00")]
rawData["2018-04-24"] = [
    ShowData(id: "5vj9t1i5B4J3", time: "17:00:00"),
    ShowData(id: "um7UeNPJuAcv", time: "20:00:00")]
rawData["2018-04-25"] = [
    ShowData(id: "AbS69J4SM4gG", time: "17:00:00"),
    ShowData(id: "AbS69J4SM4gG", time: "20:00:00")]

for key in rawData.keys {
    print(key)
}
```

For me, this prints out...

```
2018-04-25
2018-04-24
2018-04-23
2018-04-21
2018-04-20
2018-04-22
```

Now, you could look to finding a `OrderedDictionary` or you could `Map` the keys to an array and sort the array, which would give you vector back into the `Dictionary`

Or, you could sort the `Entry` data of the `Dictionary`...

```
let sorted = rawData.sorted { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    return lhs.key < rhs.key
}

for entry in sorted {
    print(entry.key)
}
```

Which outputs...

```
2018-04-20
2018-04-21
2018-04-22
2018-04-23
2018-04-24
2018-04-25
```

Now, what's important to remember here is, this is nothing more then a `String` comparison, but you're dealing with dates.  Personally, I hate dealing with `String` date/time values and as soon as I can, I convert to something which is actually practical for there purpose...

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"

let actuallySortedByDate = rawData.sorted { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    return formatter.date(from: lhs.key)! < formatter.date(from: rhs.key)!
}

for entry in sorted {
    print(entry.key)
}
```

Which outputs...

```
2018-04-20
2018-04-21
2018-04-22
2018-04-23
2018-04-24
2018-04-25
```

While this might not look any different from the first sorting, the comparisons performed are more actual to the data type (date objects).

## Important

This is a demonstration of an idea.  It's very important to understand that it's possible for the key to be invalid and the `Date` conversion to fail.  Personally, I'd prefer to have the `rawData` keyed by `Date`, rather the `String` as it allows for an earlier detection of the issue.  I've used a "forced unwrap" in the example purely for demonstration - you should validate the keys before hand and ensure that data is correct

*Caveat:* Mapping the keys in a `Dictionary` is actually a lot harder then it would seem to need to be. You can have a look at [What's the cleanest way of applying map() to a dictionary in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116271/whats-the-cleanest-way-of-applying-map-to-a-dictionary-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for more details.  Needs less to say, use Swift 4!

Okay, so what this attempts to do, is convert the original `[String: ShowData]` `Dictionary` to a `[Date: ShowData]` `Dictionary` in a way which would allow you to deal with the possibility of invalid `String` keys.

```
enum ParserError: Error {
    case invalidDateFormat
}

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
do {
    let mapped = try Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: rawData.map({ (entry) throws -> (Date, [ShowData]) in
        guard let date = formatter.date(from: entry.key) else {
            throw ParserError.invalidDateFormat
        }
        return (Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).startOfDay(for: date), entry.value)
    }))

    let actuallySortedByDate = mapped.sorted { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
        return lhs.key < rhs.key
    }
    
    for entry in actuallySortedByDate {
        print(entry.key)
    }
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

And this eventually ends up printing:

```
2018-01-19 13:00:00 +0000
2018-01-20 13:00:00 +0000
2018-01-21 13:00:00 +0000
2018-01-22 13:00:00 +0000
2018-01-23 13:00:00 +0000
2018-01-24 13:00:00 +0000
```

*ps: The idea is to try and take the time component out of the equation*

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are unordered. You will also find that dealing with variable keys (your dates) can be tricky too. You should make `instances` an array and put the date in a dictionary value.

If you do this then you can make a couple of `struct`s that adopt `Codable` and reduce your JSON parsing down to 1 line